# how to speedup mysql server operations in

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have developed php application working with 20000 records from mysql table now i am facing slow connection problem.

it takes 15-20 seconds to retrive more then 1000 records and 5-6 secords to retrive only 5 records.

so is there any way to speedup mysql operation.
i have used xampp 1.3.2 and mysql version 5.5.32

thanx

Comment: Indexes are always good. If you're running multiple queries, consider stored procedures. Other than that, you aren't going to get much help without providing more details about your problem (sample code, etc).

Comment: [1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df18a/6  I have structure and query like fidddle. and have 200 of companies and 21000 records in table ...pls help me

Comment: I don't understand why you have the subselect. Does this query run faster and also do what you want? SELECT DISTINCT(customer) AS thecustomer, SUM(amount) AS total_amo FROM yearly_sales WHERE unit = 'PUNE' GROUP BY customer

Comment: thanx @joao but it still works slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20000 records is nothing for MySQL, performance of query depends on many factors,

1. tables design
2. using indexes
3. optimized queries

Answer (score 1):

you can create index on table! 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 1):

You said you are running XAMPP... if you are on Windows then install the full mysql enviroment and you will get much better performance. Get the [Community Edition from mysql.com](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/).

If you are running Linux, make sure mysql is installed as a service and not as an application. You may also be interested in upgrating to [mariaDB](https://mariadb.org/).

Aside from that, use indexes for all the query parameters you are using (those in your where caluse).

Also, note that some MySQL engines are faster than others, for example MyISAM may run faster than InnoDB at expense of the lack of real foreign keys.

Comment: I am using windows server 2008